# R Shiny - how to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

How can I add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to a Shiny app?

I want to call the Shiny app via ajax below:

```
<div id='include-from-outside'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.get('//127.0.1.1:3838/', {}, function(data, status, xhr) {
        var updatedData = data.replace(/\/(images|stylesheets|javascripts|vendors|fonts)+/g, "http://127.0.1.1:3838/$1");

        $('#include-from-outside').html(updatedData);
    });
</script>
```

But I get this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.1.1' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The easy way is to just add the extension in google chrome to allow access using CORS.

(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US)

Just enable this extension whenever you want allow access to no 'access-control-allow-origin' header request.

Comment: thanks. but probably we can't ask the users to add that. shiny is really really a bad framework. too much limitations!

Comment: This happens because you are doing an HttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. You have to do something like this. Check this link [Using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: Unfortunately, setting CORS headers is just available for Shiny Server Pro (see this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1225))