# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Shiny Server (Non Pro)?

Tags: javascript, r, angular, cors, shiny-server

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.131.12.49:8010/get.me.data?opt=All' from origin 'http://localhost:1826' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am calling HttpRequest through Angular Framework.

I tried with [R Shiny - how to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230683/r-shiny-how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin/43230926)

but we can't say every user to install particular extension to use this.

As you all know shiny server pro is not open source & it would get out of budget of our project. So is there any permanent solution to fix this?

```
export class DashboardService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://10.131.12.49:8010/get.me.data?opt=All';

  //jsonp: any;
  constructor(
    // private http: Http, 
    private http:HttpClient,
  ) { }

  CustReport() {  
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
  }
```

Expecting result:

```
[{"AVG_THROUGHPUT":1976.0432,"AVG_DCR":0.0919}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shiny server (non pro) doesn't support setting custom headers. So in this case  you can create a simple http server, that proxies your requests to shiny server. And then use http://proxyserver/{path} for API calls.

```js
const http = require("http");
const httpProxy = require("http-proxy");

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.oldWriteHead = res.writeHead;
  res.writeHead = (statusCode, headers) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    res.oldWriteHead(statusCode, headers);
  };

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  proxy.web(req, res, {
    // Target to Shiny server
    target: "http://10.131.12.49:8010"
  });
});

server.listen(5050);
console.log("listening on port 5050");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify the server. this approach won’t work if we took into account the context in which you are.
I suggest that you use your backend as a middleware between your angular App and The Shiney Server.
For that you can make an endpoint in your backend like:

**`/api/cors?url=http://10.131.12.49:8010/get.me.data?opt=All`**